# Verb for "meet frequently or even daily, spending time together on quotidian activities"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a verb meaning "meet frequently or even daily, spending time together on quotidian activities".

E.g.:
I hope I can < verb > with you again in the future.
Looking forward to < verb>-ing with you again.

This verb could be applied in the context of working with someone.
It could also be used if you live just next door to a friend and one frequently walks into the other's house. However, it can't be used if you meet your friend just a couple of times every year or if you talk to them on the telephone but don't meet.

In Portuguese, one could use the verb "conviver" for that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is an informal or slang term *[hang](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hang)* (or *hang out* or *hang around*) that means

> To spend one's free time in a certain place. Often used with around or out: *liked to hang out at the pool hall.*

*American Heritage*

This is probably an Americanism.

Comment: the "meet frequently or even daily" part of the "definition" is not implied by the term _hang_, is it?

Comment: Not explicitly, but the term is often used for a routine pattern of association.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***associate with someone***.

> : to be friendly with someone; to be acquainted with someone socially in
>   a work setting. *We seek to associate with persons like ourselves.* *I
>   like to associate with interesting people.* [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/associate+with)

Comment: imagine Jack is my friend. During one year, we work together everyday. On the second year, he travels abroad and we don't meet for twelve months. On the third year, he is back to the country and we are flatmates. Could I say that I associate with Jack in the first and third years, but not in the the second one?

Comment: @tolivieira Yes, you could. https://books.google.fr/books?id=Mx87AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%22been+associating+with%22+%22on+and+off%22&source=bl&ots=JAxM3HdSXU&sig=8TZadaZktsl6PLs1IJaNQF2IhJQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi67fKgp8vJAhXM1hQKHZjfChAQ6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=%22been%20associating%20with%22%20%22on%20and%20off%22&f=false

Comment: sorry to insisit but, in the example ("Austin had been associating with June on and off since she was 16.") _to associate with_ doesn't seem to mean something like "to spend time together on quotidian activities" but rather "to work together in a common business or task" .